# How Tomcat 8 Handles websocket upgrade request

Tags: tomcat, websocket, tomcat8

I want to understand handling of websocket upgrade request in tomcat ? Is it done via filters or servlets ? How the ws upgrade request is handled by TOmcat-8.

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat uses a filter to look for the HTTP upgrade request that starts a WebSocket connection and passes it the the appropriate handler if it sees one.

The Filter is configured using a ServletContainerInitializer. The location of the Filter will depend on what other Filters are configured by the web application and where the web application places them in the FilterChain. It is possible, for example, that a web application would wish to place a security filter before the Web Socket filter and Tomcat allows this.

Comment: Be careful, this is undefined behavior by the `javax.websocket` spec. This is an open bug against that specific spec - see [WEBSOCKET_SPEC-188](https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC-188)

Comment: @MarkThomas: How do you check a request to determine if it is a websocket request or an HTTP request?

Comment: Tomcat looks for the HTTP upgrade headers defined in the WebSocket spec and for a matching URI for a registered endpoint. If both are found then the request is passed to WebSocket otherwise the Filter just passes it to the next Filter in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets are a completely different protocol. They are not handled by filters or servlets but instead by EndPoints. To create them you use to extend the endpoint class but, like everything else in Java EE, you can now use annotations. For more info check out the latest doc [Java API for WebSockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm)

To create them on the client side the request starts in HTTP, perhaps in JavaScript, but on Tomcat the endpoint is listening, not your normal servlets.

Comment: That's correct !! But Tomcat has to find the way to handle websocket upgrade request. I want to know how Tomcat handles upgrade request ? For example jetty has a ws upgrade filter in the front which does upgrade as soon as request hits the filters.

Comment: I checked the source code and understood that "org/apache/tomcat/websocket/server/WsFilter.java" handles the upgrade of websocket. PLease let me know if my understanding is correct ?  Also is this filter will be the first filter which will get invoked, any other ordering of filters specified by tomcat ?