# Clarification on websocket

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I am exploring Websocket now. I need some clarifications. I am using websocket with tomcat.

How tomcat map websocket requests to specific java class. for an example, we can give servlet class in web.xml. But How it works for websocket?

Answer (score 0):

1- Javascript :
Declare  variables for the websocket as the following :
var websocket;
var address = "ws://localhost:8080/appName/MyServ";

notice that appName is your application name and MyServ is the Endpoint

also in your script add a function to open the connection :

```
var websocket;
var address = "ws://localhost:8080/appName/MyServ";
function openWS() {

    websocket = new WebSocket(address);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
        onOpen(evt) 
    };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
        onMessage(evt)
    };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
        onError(evt)
    };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) {
        onClose(evt)
    };
}

function onOpen(evt) {
   // what will happen after opening the websocket
}

function onClose(evt) {
    alert("closed")   
}
function onMessage(evt) {
    // what do you want to do when the client receive the message?
   alert(evt.data);
}

function onError(evt) {
   alert("err!")
}

function SendIt(message) {
// call this function to send a msg
    websocket.send(message);
}
```

2- At the server side, you need a ServerEndpoint : I call it myServ in the script above.

NOW, I think this is exactly what you need:

Declare any Java POJO class WebSocket server endpoint by annotating it with @ServerEndpoint

```
import java.io.IOException
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value="/MyServ") 
public class MyServ{
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String msg) throws IOException { 
        // todo when client send msg
        // tell the client that you received the message!
       try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("I got your message :"+ msg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen (Session session) {
      // tell the client the connection is open!

     try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("it is open!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose (Session session) {
        System.out.println("websocket closed");

    }

    @OnError
    public void onError (Session session){ 

    }
}
```

Comment: this is fine :) but how this ws request reach its destination? how tomcat handled it?

Comment: This is to open a connection at the client side websocket = new WebSocket( "ws://localhost:8080/appName/MyServ");
and then, at the server side, there is a ServerEndpoint, @ServerEndpoint(value="/MyServ") . Tomcat looks to request header and for matching URI. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103939/how-tomcat-8-handles-websocket-upgrade-request