# Getting client IP ADDRESS when using ServerEndpoint

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-websocket

Means, that it will get connections from many users in local web. How can i get IP address each single connection? I use JSR356.

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/example")
public class ExampleServlet {

     private static final AtomicInteger connectionIds = new AtomicInteger(0);
     private static final Set<ExampleServlet> connections = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();
     private Session session;

     @OnOpen
     public void start(Session session) {
         this.session = session;
         connections.add(this);
     }

     @OnClose
     public void end() {
     }

     @OnMessage
     public void incoming(String message) {
     }

     @OnError
     public void onError(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, JSR356 Websocket specification does not expose client IP address. Solution, how to hack this, i found there: [JSR-356 WebSockets with Tomcat - How to limit connections within single IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880055/jsr-356-websockets-with-tomcat-how-to-limit-connections-within-single-ip-addre)

Answer (score -1):

this is for websocket with spring
        @Override
            public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session)      throws Exception {
                      System.out.println("connectionestablished!"+session.getLocalAddress());
    }

Comment: its not about jsf ,spring.you can get it from session.

Comment: OP is using standard Java EE, not the 3rd party Spring library. You're not answering the concrete question at all. If you want to answer Spring questions, look for Spring questions.